# How do I multiply column cells and add NaN where number isn't there?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 22.50},
               {'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter', 'Cost': 2.50},
               {'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': '...'}],
              index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

How can I multiply all cells in a 'Cost' column by a number and if a number isn't there (e.g. '...') the cell becomes NaN?

I tried multiply() but no success so far :/

So if I start with this:

[image]

I want to multiply the column by 2 so I get result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_numeric()`:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Cost, errors='coerce') * 2
```